# Question mark "?" substitution for CREATE TABLE, DROP TABLE in SQL - Limitations

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I'm new to SQL and working on figuring out how to write clean/efficient SQL commands.

I'm using the sqlite3 package from Python, and I'm trying to use question mark substitution combined with the executemany() function to write efficient commands.

I've seen examples like this:

```
with sql.connect("db_file.db") as conn:
    cur = conn.cursor()
    purchases = [('2006-03-28', 'BUY', 'IBM', 1000, 45.00),
                 ('2006-04-05', 'BUY', 'MSFT', 1000, 72.00),
                 ('2006-04-06', 'SELL', 'IBM', 500, 53.00),
                ]
    cur.executemany('INSERT INTO stocks VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)', purchases)
    conn.close()
```

And I'm wondering if I can use similar syntax for creating/dropping tables:

```
with sql.connect("db_file.db") as conn:
    cur = conn.cursor()
    tables = ["MajorInfo",
                "CourseInfo",
                "StudentInfo",
                "StudentGrades"]
    cur.executemany("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS (?);", tables)
    conn.close()
```

The code above throws the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sql_test.py", line 4, in <module>
    sql1.student_db()
  File "/acmeshare/jastern/byu_vol2/SQL1/sql1.py", line 57, in student_db
    cur.executemany("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS (?);", tables)
  sqlite3.OperationalError: near "(": syntax error
```

Is what I am attempting possible in SQL? Is there a conventional way to do what I am attempting? Thanks!

#### Update:

To verify that the issue was not with the `executemany()` function, I tried:

```
table = "MajorInfo"
cur.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ?;", table)
conn.close()
```

and got a `sqlite3.OperationalError: near "?": syntax error`. I'm thinking that ? substitution may be limited to use only in the `INSERT INTO` and `SELECT` commands.

Comment: Does it work if you just remove the parentheses? Like `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ?`?

Comment: Nope, tried `cur.executemany("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ?;", tables)` and got `OperationalError: near "?": syntax error`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQLite's statement [`DROP TABLE`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_droptable.html) doesn't accept parameters in parentheses. Also, it doesn't accept multiple parameters so what you want is most likely not possible, unfortunately.

The `DROP TABLE` statement is defined as:

[image: DROP TABLE definition]

Comment: Usually only DML statements accept parameters (insert, update, delete, select). DDL statements usually do not.

Comment: @TheImpaler Do you mean "multiple parameters" by "parameters". Because even DDL statements accept parameters. In case of `DROP TABLE`, the parameter is `schema-name.table-name`.

Comment: @DawidFerency I may be wrong. Not an expert on Python. In general, prepared statements only accept parameters on DML statements, since the database need to pre-process them on their side. This may not be the case here, since they may be only processed in the client side (not sure).

Comment: @TheImpaler Oh, got it, you meant prepared statements, not queries themselves. Well, I don't know.

Comment: For what it's worth, you can use `?` variables in place of values (such as literals), not identifiers such as table or column names.